# PHP file_get_contents() returns wrong encoding

Tags: php, encoding, file-get-contents

Try to read an XML feed from the following URL: http://www.mister-baseball.com/feed/

However, the output is somehow encoded wrongly and I can't figure out how to fix this. My code looks as follows:

```
$url = "http://www.mister-baseball.com/feed/";
// Check the cache first
$error = false;
if (!file_exists($cacheFile) || filemtime($cacheFile) < (time() - 60 * 5)) {
  if ($xmlString = @file_get_contents($url, FILE_TEXT)) {
    // WHEN I PRINT THE $xmlString HERE, IT LOOKS BAD
    file_put_contents($cacheFile, $xmlString, LOCK_EX);
  } else {
    // THIS PART IS NOT REACHED
    $logDate = date('d-M-Y H:i:s');
    error_log("[$logDate] Cannot open XML news feed at $url");
    $error = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "encoded" wrong? Can you add a small sample?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you intended with FILE_EXT in file_get_contents. You should only need `file_get_contents($url)`

Answer (score 3):

The url is returning a gzip.  After writing the cache file, open it with winrar or 7zip and you will see.

Comment: Is not necessary to manually unzip feed

Comment: I don't expect him to.  I suggested manually opening the file so he could see for himself.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has builtin this function.

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php

You can use:

`simplexml_load_file("compress.zlib://http://www.mister-baseball.com/feed/")`

OR

`file_get_contents('compress.zlib://http://www.mister-baseball.com/feed/');`

Comment: This method helps you ?